# Tenho duas classes uma contem o metodo fileupload e save file... quero a partir do MB chamar essa classe, qual a maneira mais correta

Tags: jsf, primefaces

segue a classe fileupload

```
public class FileUpload{

private String destination="D:\\tmp\\";

public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    // Do what you want with the file        
    try {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}  

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
       try {


            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("New file created!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
}
```

Quero chamar esse método `doUpload` do meu `ManagedBean`, ele esta em um pacote separado porque vai ser reutilizado varias vezes

```
@managedBean
public class MBminhaTela{

chamar objeto doUpload da classe FileUpload

}
```

Comment: Já verificou no showcase como fazer?

Comment: o metodo está direto no managedBean o que eu quero é chamar este método de um pacote util

Comment: Certo, este método vai ser estático?

Comment: seria a melhor forma de chamá-lo

Comment: Se eu entendi, certo vc quer chamar o método de uma classe estatica dentro da classe mbMinhaTela correto? Se for, é só chamar o método ué...